# JOOQ throws DataTypeException when fetching table meta

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

Getting an error when trying to fetch table meta data.

Using:
JOOQ 3.14.0,
PostgeSQL 12,
PostgreSQL driver 42.2.10

Example:

```
@RestController
@ApiVersion("v2")
public class TypeResource {
    private final DSLContext ctx;

    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public void test(@RequestParam String table) {
        ctx.meta().getTables(table);
    }
}
```

Error (This is not the whole error but the rest is similar):

```
17:16:44.808 [http-nio-8181-exec-5] [WARN ] org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl - Default value            : Could not load default value: '{}'::character varying[] for type: varchar ([Ljava.lang.String;)
org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from '{}'::character varying[] (class java.lang.String) to class [Ljava.lang.String;
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.fail(Convert.java:1303)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.from(Convert.java:1192)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert0(Convert.java:392)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:384)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:458)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDataType.convert(AbstractDataType.java:534)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.convert(DefaultDataType.java:86)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:24373)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.inline(DSL.java:23891)
    at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl$MetaTable.init(MetaImpl.java:910)
    at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl$MetaTable.<init>(MetaImpl.java:560)
    at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl$MetaSchema.getTables(MetaImpl.java:421)
    at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl.getTables0(MetaImpl.java:217)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractMeta$4.iterator(AbstractMeta.java:194)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractMeta.get(AbstractMeta.java:340)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractMeta.initTables(AbstractMeta.java:191)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractMeta.getTables(AbstractMeta.java:172)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractMeta.getTables(AbstractMeta.java:167)
17:16:44.843 [http-nio-8181-exec-5] [WARN ] org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl - Default value            : Could not load default value: '{{0,0}}'::numeric[] for type: numeric ([Ljava.math.BigDecimal;)
org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from '{{0,0}}'::numeric[] (class java.lang.String) to class [Ljava.math.BigDecimal;
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.fail(Convert.java:1303)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.from(Convert.java:1192)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert0(Convert.java:392)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:384)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:458)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDataType.convert(AbstractDataType.java:534)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.convert(DefaultDataType.java:86)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:24373)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.inline(DSL.java:23891)
    at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl$MetaTable.init(MetaImpl.java:910)
    at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl$MetaTable.<init>(MetaImpl.java:560)
    at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl$MetaSchema.getTables(MetaImpl.java:421)
    at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl.getTables0(MetaImpl.java:217)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractMeta$4.iterator(AbstractMeta.java:194)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractMeta.get(AbstractMeta.java:340)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractMeta.initTables(AbstractMeta.java:191)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractMeta.getTables(AbstractMeta.java:172)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractMeta.getTables(AbstractMeta.java:167)
```

Example table create script :

```
CREATE TABLE public.user_role
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_role_id_seq'::regclass),
    user_id bigint NOT NULL,
    role_id bigint NOT NULL,
    ts_created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ts_updated timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_by_user character varying(256) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n/a'::character varying,
    updated_by_process character varying(64) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n/a'::character varying,
    CONSTRAINT user_role_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT x_role_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (role_id)
        REFERENCES public.role (id) MATCH FULL
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT x_user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public."user" (id) MATCH FULL
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.user_role
    OWNER to postgres;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX x_role_user_id_role_id_uq
    ON public.user_role USING btree
    (user_id ASC NULLS LAST, role_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Initially my goal was to get the table indexes and this is working fine.
I tried to update JOOQ from 3.13.1 to 3.14.0 and tested with different tables in the database but without any luck.

Comment: That's probably a bug. Do you have any such expressions like `{{0,0}}'::numeric[]` in your table definitions' `DEFAULT` clauses, or where does it appear? Can you post an example `CREATE TABLE` statement that helps reproducing this?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I attached example create script which i took from pgadmin.

Comment: @LukasEder i tried to pass table name that does not exist and i get the same exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug which will be fixed in jOOQ 3.15 via https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8469. jOOQ currently assumes that `DatabaseMetaData` column descriptions produce values for `DEFAULT` expressions, instead of expressions.

The bug is "cosmetic", as it only affects your logs. The field is still produced correctly (without any `DEFAULT` expression). You can mute the message in your logger configuration until the above bug is fixed.